# Why is everyone so helpful?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, users

I’m very grateful that so many people help and even take time to write code to make examples, but my question is why? How come people take their time to look for questions and help?

It sounds dumb, but this site in particular has a lot of people helping all the time. Is this normal for the programmer community? From all the communities, forums, etc., this has been the most active group that look to help other. Maybe I just got used to people not caring for others unless there’s a reward.

Comment: Related: [What motivates people to answer questions in Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3742/what-motivates-people-to-answer-questions-in-stack-overflow) and [Why do I get more satisfaction out of participating in SO than out of my job?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28642/why-do-i-get-more-satisfaction-out-of-participating-in-so-than-out-of-my-job). I know that there also a question on this meta, but seems like my google foo is broken today.

Comment: Because it is self-serving while simultaneously helping others.

Comment: I have to admit this is a nice change from the usual "why is everyone so toxic" and "let's cancel downvotes". I'm happy you enjoy the site and find people helpful. Hope it stays that way!

Comment: @Tomerikoo: Indeed. We need counters, like this statement, to something like *[The Tyrannical Mods of Stack Overflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IbDAmvUwo5c)* (which is full of factual inaccuracies and misunderstandings (and irritating background music), but that is not the point).

Comment: Technically speaking, there *are* rewards, in the form of reputation and badges. Granted, they're just imaginary Internet points, and most people here aren't in it for the rep, but you'd be surprised at how seriously some people take them.

Comment: Anything I can do to improve the hiring pool makes my job easier.

Comment: This is from a different Stack Exchange site (Meta Ask Ubuntu), but see also [Why are there so many helpful people?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/18386/1438484)

Comment: after more than a decade of "read only" on SO, I for one felt the need to balance karma a little, I took a lot, it is justice to give back (as far as I can)

Comment: For one every single semi-competent developer has needed the help of someone else even if it's to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging, so most of us like to return the favour. IMHO Development in all walks of life is iterative we're building on top of the work of others so support others to build work we might end up building on top of in the future.

Comment: *"It sounds dumb, but this site in particular has a lot of people helping all the time"* ... Well sort of. You help yourself because that is the purpose of the site, to allow you to find solutions. 'The people' help the site, by filling it. Technically it shouldn't be called helping if it is kind of a selfish act, we all want the site to stick around because it saves our butts at work.

Answer (score 20):

I feel like this is explained pretty well in the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour):

> With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming.

We know that certain problems are often encountered by our fellow developers. This is why we spend our free time here to produce a sizeable repository of information so that people facing the same programming task in the future do not need to ask the same question again, but can instead look up the solution to their problem online.

We just want to share our knowledge for the betterment of the programming community.

Comment: As an "answerer" here, I'd like to add that I am often one of these "people facing the same programming task in the future". I don't do answer (only) out of generosity. Trying to solve the problems others do face today is solving the problems I will face tomorrow.

Comment: It's pretty simple, you get what you give.. if you can help someone solve an issue then one day someone is going to turn around and help you solve yours. It's karma

Answer (score 19):

### Why I answer here

1. **Wanting to help**: It feels right.  Simple.
2. **Appreciation and wanting to give back**:  My answers are a modest thank you to the Stack Overflow and wider programming communities for all their help over the years.
3. **Respect for the scoring system:** Despite the criticism it receives and despite its shortcomings, at the heart of the scoring system is a practical and successful means of surfacing reasonably reliable information.  This has lead to a symbiotic relationship with search engines, which has lead to a substantial audience here.  By enabling me to answer individual's questions with future readers' needs in mind, the SO platform amplifies my help effort.  I like that.
4. **Getting better**: Answering questions sharpens one's own understanding.

Answer (score 14):

I learned programming pretty much entirely during the time Stack Overflow was around, and (like just about everyone else) discovered it googling errors and warnings I'd run into.

So there's a sense of wanting to give back, and understanding that not everyone I help is going to leave an upvote or a comment, or understand the culture, or even have an account. For many years I didn't (plus was under 13 so I'd never say!).

Now, I get a genuine sense of excitement when I encounter an error or warning and googling it *does not* lead me here, because it means I may get to solve something new and document my findings for others.

Especially when it's something I can sense a lot of people are about to start encountering (when [M1 Macs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1#Products_that_use_the_Apple_M1_series) first came out, setting up [Mastodon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastodon_(software)) servers, etc.)

Comment: Also those who learnt programming before Internet resources/documentation became mainstream (around year 2000), might recalling solely relying on taking classes, reading brick-sized books, `man` and compiler help files. Which worked fine until the point where you get stuck using something like for example a rare API/library function. It got painful when you had exhausted all available documentation about it and still not solved the problem. Now you can just ask on SO and then you might just get an answer from someone who is an expert on using that particular function.

Comment: @Lundin Do you think newsgroups were not mainstream before 2000?

Comment: @Bergi Internet as whole before year ~2000 was not mainstream. Newsgroups was something used by a few stray nerds here and there, not by the average Internet user. As an example, Microsoft didn't even have online documentation before year 2000.

Answer (score 8):

I'll speak for myself. I'm an "experienced" (==="old") programmer, who laid down his first line of code in 1969.  Back then, the only way to figure out problems was to scour the printed manuals and learn to inspect crash dumps, again printed on line printer paper. There weren't many libraries ([npm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_(software)), [PHP Composer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composer_(software)), [NuGet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet), and the like weren't even imagined). If I wanted an algorithm created by somebody else, I'd type it in from [Byte magazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_(magazine)) or a textbook, or beg the author to send it to me on Hollerith punch-cards or [DECtape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DECtape) or something. This limited the scope of what we could accomplish. Getting anything done requires deep expertise in the language and toolchain as well as the problem domain.

Then program libraries started to appear. I'd send US$25 to some user club and they'd send me back a 9-track magnetic tape full of code I could use. But I was limited by the quality of the documentation (often just comments) in the code.

Then [Usenet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet) newsgroups came on the scene. I could ask questions and get answers, but the quality of answers was Twitterish -- 10% good stuff, 90% BS. I quickly realized that I should *answer* a few questions, in a quest to raise the ratio to 10.1% good stuff. That way others might see the benefit of answering carefully.

**And, I discovered that the discipline of answering questions taught me a lot about my trade.**

At the same time, programming gradually changed. Because code libraries started to proliferate, programming became a trade where broad knowledge was important. Good debuggers and IDEs, not to mention memory-safe languages, meant that deep knowledge of toolchains became less important. Broad knowledge means, basically, knowing how to look things up.

Then expertSexChange(dot)com came and went. It was annoying; goofball paywalls, and all that. But it had some decent answers. (Why anybody would go for gender-reassignment surgery by anybody other than an expert, I don't know. :-) -:).

Then Stack Overflow appeared. Joel Spolsky, Jeff Atwood, and their colleagues figured out how to build a crowd-sourced curation system so the good questions and answers would be highlighted. And, they figured out a good SEO system, so Google would find the good answers. (They must have had a lot of cooperation from Google people; their SEO is really really good.)

They monetized Stack Overflow by building a recruiting system; their curation system assigns points to people who know what they're talking about in specific fields. I got a good job once via Stack Overflow, and I've hired some good people that way. Thanks Joel and Jeff!

The rest is history.

I'm in the giving-back phase of my career now, and I still like learning about peoples' problems and helping solve them.

Answer (score 2):

My reason for giving back is that frequently my search efforts would lead to helpful answers (and interesting questions) here and on other Stack Exchange sites.

The way we *repay* for the assistance is by offering equally helpful answers and the occasional interesting question.

Thank you for past assistance, and an extra thanks to the experts who take time from their busy day to go the extra mile.

Answer (score 0):

Because people have a huge weak spot for watching numbers going up, and like getting attention. It's the same principle behind all social media, incremental games, investment, etc.

Also helping people, present and future, feels nice. But that also applies to other forums where people are generally less helpful.

[image]

Comment: What are some examples of other forms?

Comment: I think the left circle is meant to say "Forums"? SO is decidedly _not_ a forum, though.

Comment: Mostly tech specific forms like the unity forms, monogame forms, rust forms etc. as well as github issues that also don't have scoring. While there are still often helpful answers there bad questions typically just get ignored instead of given tips how to improve

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm specifically contrasting SO to normal forms

Answer (score -3):

Why is everyone so helpful? Well, because people like you are ready to be helped.

The SE networks set for themselves a high standard for question contents, and you've probably met it. There are many unfortunate new users posting poorly thought-out questions that get downvoted and even get closed. The fact you find SO helpful is an indicator that you're a good contributor.

Comment: Downvoting someone is in a way also helping people. It is a clear indicator that they have  issues with their posts and can motivate people to seek out and understand why that is -- in the process improving themselves and their future questions

Comment: This really is a nice real-world example.